# Как в Qt coздать всплывающие подсказки?

Tags: qt, интерфейс, pyqt

Хотелось бы реализовать интерактивную систему подсказок в Qt диалоге, что-то на подобии этого:
[image]

Возможно ли это в принципе и какие классы для этого лучше всего подойдут?

Comment: У виджетов есть поле toolTip,  или statusTip

Comment: tooltip появляется только когда мышка находится над объектом, и он может появиться только один на все окошко. Мне необходимо отобразить несколько подсказок в одном окне, чтобы пользователь мог их сам позакрывать, когда все прочитает..

Comment: Наследуйтесь от `QWidget` и рисуйте всё, что пожелаете, а потом размещайте эти объекты в тех местах, что Вам нужны.